# For each row with a week number value, how do I count the number of rows from the previous weeks?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

So I have this table where each row is an order, and the `week` value stands for the nth week of the year that the order was placed:

| orderId | customerId | week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 35 |
| 2 | 1 | 35 |
| 3 | 2 | 35 |
| 4 | 1 | 36 |
| 5 | 1 | 37 |
| 6 | 1 | 38 |

I want to be able to add 2 other columns: `week-1_orders` and `prev-weeks_orders`:

| orderId | customerId | week | week-1_orders | prev-weeks_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 35 |  |  |
| 2 | 1 | 35 |  |  |
| 3 | 2 | 35 |  |  |
| 4 | 1 | 36 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 37 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 1 | 38 | 1 | 4 |

**week-1_orders** gets the count of orders placed by the same customer within the week before the current row's week.
So if we're looking at the row of `orderId = 4` where `week = 36`, the same customer (`customerId = 1`) placed 2 orders in the previous week (`week = 35`). `orderId = 3` is not counted since it is not placed by `customerId = 1`. Thus, `week-1_orders = 2`.

The same goes for **prev-weeks_orders**, except that it counts all the previous weeks instead of just 1 single week.

I was hoping to somehow be able to refer to the current row's value like this, although I can't seem to find a way:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN orders."week" = curr_row."week" - 1 AND orders."customerId" = curr_row."customerId" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "week-1_orders",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN orders."week" <= curr_row."week" - 1 AND orders."customerId" = curr_row."customerId" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "prev-week_orders"
FROM orders
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [scalar subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) would be the easiest to read.

```sql
select orderid, customerid, week,
    (select count(*) from the_table where customerid = tx.customerid and week = tx.week - 1) "week-1 orders",
    (select count(*) from the_table where customerid = tx.customerid and week < tx.week) "prev-weeks orders"
from the_table as tx;
```

Or using a [lateral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql) join with a subquery

```
select orderid, customerid, week, l.*
from the_table as tx cross join lateral     
(
 select 
   count(*) filter (where customerid = tx.customerid and week = tx.week - 1) "week-1 orders",
   count(*) filter (where customerid = tx.customerid and week < tx.week) "prev-weeks orders"
 from the_table
) as l;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9NhegohLL6Z7KKdsQx1sr1/2)

There might be a good solution using window functions too.

Comment: FIrst one you mentioned worked perfectly for me. Thanks!